# nginx + php-fpm give me too big error log

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I use nginx and php-fpm to deploy many wordpress in one service (centos). I have turn off `log_errors` in /etc/php.ini, but i still get a lot of error log.

[image]

[image]

Comment: remind to rotate yozr logs.... 138gb is a damn nize log moreover ut look for a straight attack as mostly the same picture are there

Comment: Please add logs as texts, screenshots are difficult to read.